# mysqldbcompare object definitions differ

Tags: replication, mysql-5.7, galera

I am using a Galera cluster to replicate MySQL 5.7 databases on Ubuntu 16.04 Server. I am using mysqldbcompare to verify the consistency of the replication. I think my data is consistent because the Data Checks and Row Count checks pass.

I think "Object definitions differ..." means that there is something different about the CREATE statements. My output shows the Auto Increment fields having some differences.

My question is: Will the inconsistencies in the object definitions affect the consistency of my replicated databases as a whole (even though data check passes)?

I would love to know what causes the inconsistencies and how to fix them.

```
# Checking databases study1 on server1 and study1 on server2
#
#                                                   Defn    Row     Data
# Type      Object Name                             Diff    Count   Check
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# TABLE     admin_log                               pass    pass    -
#           - Compare table checksum                                pass
# TABLE     clists                                  pass    pass    -
#           - Compare table checksum                                pass
# TABLE     data1                                   FAIL    pass    -
#           - Compare table checksum                                pass
#
# Object definitions differ. (--changes-for=server1)
#

--- `study1`.`data1`
+++ `study1`.`data1`
@@ -236,4 +236,4 @@
   `sys_pagetime_29` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `sys_pagetime_30` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`sys_RespNum`)
-) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=303 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
+) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=301 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: I found this [link](https://severalnines.com/blog/galera-cluster-mysql-vs-mysql-ndb-cluster-high-level-comparison-webinar-replay-slides) that explains on slide 31 that there will be auto-increment sequence gaps as inserts are executed on different nodes. I would still like to know what this means for data consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the only table with `AUTO_INCREMENT`?

How many nodes?

`SELECT MAX(id)` from each node.

I'm pretty sure there is no data inconsistency -- each replicated statement will be done using RBR, so it will include the *actual* `id`, and not look at that setting on the `CREATE TABLE`.

(I do not know exactly where the 303 and 301 come from.)

Comment: I was using 3 nodes. There were several more tables with AUTO_INCREMENT. I don't remember where the 303 and 301 values come from. I did more consistency checking and with out the auto increment, the data was indeed consistent across all the nodes. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Possibly the 301 and 303 are the node's "last" used `AUTO_INCREMENT` value, which will _necessarily_ vary between nodes -- see `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset`;